# how to split string like 1+2-3/4

Tags: java, string, expression

I'm trying to build calculator in java. In order to build it, i have to split each integer into array. I divided each integer before and after "+" sign, by using `split("\\+")`.

But what about other operators? Can I use "-", "/", "*" while using "+"?

Comment: Well, understand that, there is even more than just splitting the string. You would have to consider precedence also.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? What is the error?

Comment: exactly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8792737/668970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use

```
for(char ch : "1+2-3/4".toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(ch);
}
```

You need to write a simple parser if you want multi-digit numbers and negative numbers i.e. `-1+-2`

In the past I have used an [enum based state machine](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/java-secret-using-enum-as-state-machine.html) to parse test.  Once you have a stream of tokens you can build precedence rules.

Comment: thanks! but i tried before. for example, user enters equation as "12+3-4". with char it will split 1 and 2, but in our case we have to obtain 12. But anyway, thanks for your help. i really appreciated it!

Comment: Thats why you need a parser to combine them. ;)  You can't just split on `-` because you don't know if it's a minus or a negative.

Comment: ok. so could you help me with this? how to deal with operator precedence?))

Comment: That's an entirely a different question.  You have to parse the text first, then deal with precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to answer your immediate question (you have to escape some operators with `\\`):

```
"1+2-3/4".split("[+\\-*/]")
```

However this discards operators, so you need something more sophisticated. Also you might want to support floating point numbers. Last but not least, once you are done with parsing, remember about operator precedence.

Comment: You are going to want to move the `-` to the beginning of the character class, or escape it.  Otherwise it will be interpreted as a range from `+` to `/`.  There is also no need to escape the `+` or `*` if they are inside of a character class.

Comment: @F.J: thanks, I forgot it's a special character as well. So much to learn about regexes...

Comment: Yeah, it can be tricky to remember how the escaping rules change with character classes, that has tripped me up multiple times.

Comment: so next question is that. how to deal with operator precedence?))

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned your problem area as calculator, I think using **stacks** to split the operand and operator and evaluate the expression would be more appropriate.

Check the famous algorithm used in many such cases [here](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~hutchins/csci241/eval.htm)